# Eslint-plugin-react + atom + sftp: cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react'

Tags: reactjs, sftp, atom-editor, eslint

My scenario:

I have VPS with react project, where I've installed eslint-plugin-react and eslint

Atom with SFTP-remote-edit plugin to connect to VPS and remote edits

Atom with linter and eslint plugins

Is it possible to use eslint via SFTP?

I have an error all the time:

> atom cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react'

and I have no idea if I did something wrong, or it's impossible to use it like this, and I have to use it locally

Comment: Is there any solution?